# Shopify 'instant search results', how to create an on-page version, same as in header? Ride Theme

Tags: ajax, shopify, liquid

I am building a large travel store for South Africa, using Shopify, with over 40k products (services),

https://plek.co.za

how can i insert an on-page version of the responsive search, same as in the header?

i.e like a google search box on the homepage, front and center

I'm using RIDE theme, i'm battling to formulate working code for this

any tips appreciated

thanks

Matthew

i tried reworking code from the header from the theme file, but i'm not winning

i'm sure someone has done this before :-)